bash colors in emacs
I have a script returning:
[0m[38;5;16m[48;5;16m▄[0m[38;5;232m[48;5;232m▄[0m[38;5;233m[48;5;232m▄[0m[38;5;233m[48;5;233m▄[0m[38;5;234m[48;5;233m▄[0m[38;5;235m[48;5;234m▄[0m[38;5;236m[48;5;234m▄[0m[38;5;236m[48;5;235m▄[0m[38;5;237m[48;5;235m▄[0m[38;5;238m[48;5;236m▄[0m
[0m[38;5;16m[48;5;16m▄[0m[38;5;232m[48;5;232m▄[0m[38;5;234m[48;5;233m▄[0m[38;5;235m[48;5;234m▄[0m[38;5;236m[48;5;235m▄[0m[38;5;237m[48;5;236m▄[0m[38;5;239m[48;5;237m▄[0m[38;5;240m[48;5;238m▄[0m[38;5;241m[48;5;239m▄[0m[38;5;243m[48;5;240m▄[0m
[0m[38;5;16m[48;5;16m▄[0m[38;5;233m[48;5;233m▄[0m[38;5;235m[48;5;234m▄[0m[38;5;236m[48;5;236m▄[0m[38;5;238m[48;5;237m▄[0m[38;5;240m[48;5;239m▄[0m[38;5;242m[48;5;240m▄[0m[38;5;244m[48;5;242m▄[0m[38;5;245m[48;5;243m▄[0m[38;5;247m[48;5;245m▄[0m
[0m[38;5;16m[48;5;16m▄[0m[38;5;233m[48;5;233m▄[0m[38;5;236m[48;5;235m▄[0m[38;5;238m[48;5;237m▄[0m[38;5;240m[48;5;239m▄[0m[38;5;243m[48;5;241m▄[0m[38;5;245m[48;5;243m▄[0m[38;5;247m[48;5;245m▄[0m[38;5;250m[48;5;248m▄[0m[38;5;252m[48;5;250m▄[0m`

Emacs opens a *Shell Command Output* buffer with these bash colors codes, once program is executed. Is there a way to see this image correctly as it was executed inside a terminal (image below from a bash terminal)?


These color codes are defined for terminal.
